# find and delete files older than specific days and have specific string in filenames

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression

To delete files older than 5 days from a directory, we can use command.

```
find /directory -type f -mtime +5 -delete
```

But, in my case, I want to delete only those files having 'YYYY-MM-DD' in their names and which are older than 5  days.

Below are some example of filenames:

```
TEST_2016-11-20_14_02_52.log
server.log.2016-11-13
locsub.log.2016-12-04
wsgi.txt.2016-12-01
```

Only files having name in format '*YYYY-MM-DD*' and older than 5 days should get deleted.

How to match filenames in find command using regex ??

Comment: What version of `find` do you have?  GNU and BSD `find`s at least supports regex matching with `-regex`

Comment: test this `find -type f -mtime +5 -regextype "egrep" -regex '.*[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}.*`

Comment: @Babyy you should write that up as an answer with some exposition

Comment: @EricRenouf my answer is not e prefect! because my `regex` match with `dddd-dd-dddddd*` or `2016-99-44` or ... ; if you can edit and resolve this problem post it for answer

Comment: Has the literal date representation found to be 5 or more days old, or does the mtime of the file matter?

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU `find`:

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 \
    -regextype egrep -regex '.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[^/]*$' \
    -delete
```

The regular expression will match any string in the basename of a pathname that contains a date on the form `YYYY-MM-DD`. Note that we may also match `XXYYYY-MM-DDZZ` where `XX` and `ZZ` are some other characters.

The `[^/]*$` at the end makes sure that we're actually matching the expression against the basename of the current pathname, and means "no `/` for the rest of the string, please".

Using a shell wildcard pattern instead (easier to maintain):

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 \
    -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]*' \
    -delete
```

Note that `-mtime +5` is for files whose age as an integer number of days is **strictly** greater than 5, so 6 days and over. For files 5 days old or over, you'd need `-mtime +4`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with GNU tools, this should prevent the false-positives spoken of by Babyy:

```
find /directory -type f -mtime +5 -print | while read f; do
    n=`basename "$f"`
    d=`expr "X$n" : 'X.*\([0-9]\{4,\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2,\}\)'` # (1)
    test -n "$d" || continue                                     # (2)
    date -d "$d" >/dev/null 2>&1 && rm "$f"                      # (3)
done
```

**Remarks:**

- **(1)** assigns the date part of the file name to `d`. It includes leading
  and trailing digits. If there is no date part, then the empty string is
  assigned to `d`.
- **(2)** will skip to the next iteration if `"$d"` is the empty string.
  This is needed to prevent **(3)** from removing the file, since `date -d`
  will succeed if given the empty string as its argument. (This seems like a
  bug in GNU `date`, but maybe that behavior was intended.)
- **(3)** will remove the file if `"$d"` contains a valid date. Note that
  `date -d` will succeed if the year part of the date contains more than 4
  digits, as long as the month and day parts are valid. Now *that's* really
  future-proofing your code!